# How do I get SQL logging in Rails 4 WEBrick for a non-development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.1.2. I have some environments which are exact copies of my development environment. In other words, I created them by simply copying `config/environments/development.rb` to a file with a different name (e.g., `destaging.rb`). They differ only in the connection information in `database.yml`.

If I issue `RAILS_ENV=destaging rails s` or `rails s -e destaging` at the command line, everything works just as I desire, except that I get no SQL logging to `STDOUT`, which is a bummer.

Since my `destaging` environment is absolutely identical to my `development` environment except for different connection settings in `database.yml`, I suspect that something is looking for an environment named `development` and enabling SQL logging to `STDOUT` only if an environment with that name is active. How can I enable SQL logging to `STDOUT` for other environments launched through WEBRick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, I've discovered how to do this. First, I'm running Ruby 2.1.2 with Rails 4.1.2. If that is not your environment, your mileage may vary, though I suspect the solution will be very similar.

So, first you must modify `bin/rails`. Open this file and change it as follows. (I have posted the entire file, minus the shebang, for clarity.)

```
begin
  load File::expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'

# Here comes the important part
require 'rails/commands/server'
class Rails::Server::Options
  def parse_with_logging!(args)
    options = parse_without_logging!(args)
    options[:log_stdout] = true # Or whatever condition you want
    options
  end
  alias_method_chain :parse!, :logging
end

require 'rails/commands'
```

Since `require 'rails/commands'` executes the server immediately, monkey-patching after that line does not work. It is simply ignored. If you try to monkey-patch it *before* you require the commands, it explodes because the `Rails::Server::Options` class has not yet been defined. Thus, we have to pre-emptively require `rails/commands/server` so we can alias its `parse!` method.

Monkey-patching should almost always be a last resort, IMHO. However, I see no alternative in this case. If anyone has a better idea, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem with the same versions of Rails and Ruby, using a non-standard environment name (in your case "destaging"). However I did not want it to affect all environments, nor lose any more time to not getting work done, so I simply changed the way I start the server:

`(tail -F log/destaging.log &) && rails s`

Then afterwards to restart the server, ctrl-c as usual and then `rails s` again. The tail will keep going in the background and for all intents and purposes the experience will be like it was before this stopped working.